# How to use mpi for python for parallel cluster computing/ hpc?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, hpc, mpi4py

I've read some tutorials and documentation on MPI for python. However, I'm still not clear on how it is supposed to be used for sending jobs to separate nodes in a cluster, then combining/processing the results. It seems that you only specify the number of different processes.

Is it possible to use MPI for sending versions of the same script to separate nodes which run separately with multiprocessing, then combine the combine the results later? If this is an inappropriate use for MPI, what could do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you may submit one script to some nodes, specified in a given file. But the results are given based on each script. You cannot combine the results of more than one script on run-time, since each result is saved in some particular file (if any job scheduler used).